# Cant remove dependency from vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, dependencies

I installed vue horizontal list dependency in my project ([link to the dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-horizontal-list)) and now I cannot remove it. I tried running "npm uninstall vue-horizontal-list" many times (I also tried uninstalling it globally and with --save) and it didn't work. I also tried to clean the cache using "npm cache clean --force" and it didn't work. I keep getting this error when I try to run the project:

```
This dependency was not found:

* vue-horizontal-list in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel- 
loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Profile.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue-horizontal-list
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

I just want to remove it completely from the project. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to delete `node-modules` folder first and after that remove the package name from your `package.json` file. After that simply do a `npm install` and that should fix your problem. Before installing packages you could also do `npm cache clean --force` if you want but that does not change so much.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt help, I still get the same error

Comment: @McLovin did you also try removing your `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: @McLovin I am sorry but I don't see another possible resolution to this. Maybe try to fill an issue in github page of the dependency

Answer (score 1):

Try npm uninstall **nameofDependency**.
For example I installed a dependency for customizing a scroll bar npm install **simplebar-vue** --save, now I no longer need so I uninstalled it, using npm uninstall **simplebar-vue** which is the name of the dependency, then delete from your import from the main.js.